# merge string list in a comma separated string

Tags: scheme, racket, higher-order-functions

I need to write a piece of software that, given a list of strings, returns a novel string made of the comma separated concatenation of the input list elements.

```
(comma-con (list "a" "b" "c"))  ;=> "a,b,c"
```

I would love to write Scheme idiomatic code.

So far, I wrote this:

```
(define (comma-con l)
   (foldr
         (λ (x y) (if (string? y) (string-append x "," y) x))
         '()
         l))
```

That works, but it seems a bit dirty. Is there a way to write it in a better way, e.g. avoiding the "if"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`string-join`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstring..rkt%29._string-join%29%29), it does exactly what you need and is as idiomatic as it can be:

```
(string-join '("a" "b" "c") ",")
=> "a,b,c"
```

Anyway, if you want to solve the problem using a *fold*, this is a cleaner solution (assuming that the input list is non-empty):

```
(define (comma-con lst)
  (foldl (λ (e acc) (string-append acc "," e))
         (first lst)
         (rest  lst)))
```

Comment: In standard Scheme (RNRS) you'll need to import `string-join` from  the [SRFI-13 String library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-13/srfi-13.html#string-join)